# Data from collectionGroup document not loading into TextView Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I hope you are well. I am trying to add text to a text view from a document in Firestore. I was told you cant query a document by id withing a collection group, so I created a field "id" with the documentID and queried that, but still nothing and no errors.

Here is my activity:

```
public class FoodItemPage extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    ElegantNumberButton number_button;
    Button addtocart;
    TextView food_name, food_description;
    EditText extra_notes;

    String foodId;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_item_page);

        foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("foodid");
        //firestore
        Query singlefoodref = db.collectionGroup("Foods").whereEqualTo("id", foodId);
        Log.d(TAG, "well hello there" + foodId);

        //init view
        number_button = (ElegantNumberButton) findViewById(R.id.number_button);
        addtocart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addToCart);
        food_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.food_name1);
        food_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.food_description);


        singlefoodref.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(FoodItemPage.this, "document not there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    Log.d(TAG, "NOT WORKING");
                }else{

                    FoodModel foodModel = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).toObject(FoodModel.class);

                    food_name.setText(foodModel.getName());
                    Log.d(TAG, "WORKING");


                }
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(FoodItemPage.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

My model (i am also using the same Model in another activity,  that shouldn't be a problem right?) :

```
package com.example.hostapp.Models;

public class FoodModel {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String image;
    private String price;
    private String discount;
    private String categoryid;

    public FoodModel() {
    }

    public FoodModel(String name, String description, String image, String price, String discount, String categoryid) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.price = price;
        this.discount = discount;
        this.categoryid = categoryid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(String discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public String getCategoryid() {
        return categoryid;
    }

    public void setCategoryid(String categoryid) {
        this.categoryid = categoryid;
    }
}
```

Edit:
My database structure, each restaurant has its own "Foods" collections with the food items i am trying to load.

[image]

Comment: Please post your document snapshot

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: i added it the screenshot and highlighted the id i added to the food to match the document id

Comment: @AlexMamo done, let me know if there is anything else

Comment: Have you tried with a hardcoded value for `foodId`? What is the value that is returned by `getIntent().getStringExtra("foodid")`?

Comment: @AlexMamo food ID returns the ID that is highlighted, I Log.d it to test, it takes it from the previous activity. i dont get any errors at all but nothing happens

Comment: @AlexMamo yes when i do that i get an error Cannot resolve method 'toObject(java.lang.Class<com.example.hostapp.Models.FoodModel>)'

Comment: @Ashish i added it

Answer (score 0):

SO I fixed this, the error was in my database, the id in the database had a space in it so it wasn't matching the document ID from the previous activity.

so from " 123456" to "123456"